# LWC Control Workspace Tabs and Subtabs (Beta) on Dev Org

Tags: lightning-web-components, workspaceapi, lws

Are the Beta features enabled on Developer Orgs? I wanted to play around [new Workspace API for LWC](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_workspaceAPI.htm&release=246&type=5), enabled LWS on my DevOrg. Deploying such component

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { getTabInfo } from "lightning/platformWorkspaceApi";

export default class LwcWorkspaceAccount extends LightningElement {
  handleGetTabInfo() {
    const info = getTabInfo();
    console.log(info);
  }
}
```

gives me

> No MODULE named markup://lightning:platformWorkspaceApi found

What else should be done to achieve it?

Comment: It's a Beta for Winter '24 (API 59), I guess your org isn't on Winter '24, but on Summer '23. You could check it from [trust status page](https://status.salesforce.com/).

Comment: Yes, it's Summer '23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 17-Aug-2023, not yet. It may start around Aug-25.

The easiest way is to use a pre-release org (if you have one, good, otherwise you may have to wait for Aug-21 or so to create one).

More info on a digestible form at https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-winter-24-release-date-preview-information/